# Ping utility for Microsoft device emulator

Tags: ping, traceroute, emulator, pocket-pc, pda

Is there ping utility can running on Microsoft Device Emulator: both Pocket PC 2003 and Windows Mobile 5.0. Pocket PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this OpenSource utility: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pocketping/?

There is full suite of free network tools which I've used to use back in the day: [vxUtil](http://www.cambridgevx.com/vxutil.html)

Comment: Pocket Ping utility 1.8 from Pfilipp Gassmann works on emulator